# Create context menu on menu item click

Tags: android, toolbar, appbar, android-contextmenu

I am in strange situation and I tried to search everywhere but i didn't find anything useful. May be I am following bad design. But here is my situation:

I have `AppBar` in my app and I have added `ActionButton` on app bar which we do normally. Now I want to display context menu when user clicks on any of the action button of app bar.

*For example*: If I have setting button on app bar and if user clicks on that button then I want to display context menu having multiple options.
I know how to create context menu and handle context menu item clicks but i don't know *how to transfer control* from action button click which lead to display `ContextMenu`.

Here is my code:

```
//inflating context menu which will display when user clicks app bar button example like setting

    public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
        super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.context_menu_sort, menu);
    }

//handling context menu item clicks
    @Override
    public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
    }
```

But I am not sure how to handle app bar button clicks which will display context menu:

```
//Below code is to handle app bar item clicks

    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
            return true;
        }

        //handling the menu clicks on menu.xml
        switch (id){
//on below action_add click i want to display context menu
            case R.id.action_add:
//not sure what to code here
                break;
}
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

If i am understanding you right you want to show a submenu?
Then you need to add a `menu` tag in your `R.menu.context_menu_sort`.

Like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@+id/file"
          android:title="@string/file" >
        <!-- "file" submenu -->
        <menu>
            <item android:id="@+id/create_new"
                  android:title="@string/create_new" />
            <item android:id="@+id/open"
                  android:title="@string/open" />
        </menu>
    </item>
</menu>
```

For more informations see https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html